# ubuntu installer run on debian wheeze

Tags: drivers, debian-wheezy, intel-graphics, laptop-display

I have found some [intel video drivers](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) for my asus laptop "Integrated Intel® HD Graphics" but intel provided installers which are dedicated for fedora and ubuntu only; so my question is...

can I somehow run the installer on debian wheezy or somehow extract the drivers and install them manually?

p.s. currently my display is marked as "Unknown"...

Thanks

Comment: Provided you can identify the Ubuntu version with the same kernel as Wheezy, there should be no problem installing the **.deb** file, since Ubuntu is based on Debian (but you ought to back up your partition first, just in case something goes horribly wrong). I found Ubuntu supports Intel HD graphics "out of the box", so I am a little surprised that Debian doesn't, unless Wheezy is a mature release, with support in later releases. I have to admit that it was the ease with which Ubuntu supports all sorts of hardware that led me down that path.

Comment: No, the question is can I start ubuntu dedicated installer on debian?

Comment: I have always assumed that the Ubuntu installer **gdebi** is the same as Debian uses with **gnome**. If this is not so, let me know and I'll investigate further. (Sorry for delay - I've been away from home.)

Comment: @AFH No, they provide installers for ubuntu and debian only; I tried to start the installer on elementary os for example but all the time it says I am lack of libglib... >=2.37.x etc which is in some repository which is not accessible for elementaryOS etc btw there are too many dependencies which are really annoying... current eOS Luna 0.2.1 is based on ubuntu 12.04LTS but still the installer doesn't work on it - I tried; So the only way is to compile sources but I still cannot find any related info of how to do that :( ...

Comment: @AFH ...so if you know how to compile and install drivers from sources please share the detailed instructions;

Comment: I've never needed to compile from sources, except when a package is available only as source, and then I have let the makefile do all the work. I don't understand where eOS comes into the equation: your question was about Debian Wheezy. What happens when you try to use the **.deb** file in Wheezy?